# Randomly select rows from DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Okay this is somewhat tricky.  I have a DataFrame of people and I want to randomly select 27% of them.  I want to create a new Boolean column in that DataFrame that shows if that person was randomly selected.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html  If you collect the ids from the sample, you can join this back on to see if they were sampled.

Comment: `df.sample(frac=0.27)` or `df['selected'] = np.random.choice([0,1], size=len(df), p=[0.73,0.27])`?

Comment: Great, the sample function seems like a great way to do it.  But how do I create a new column that shows if a person was in the sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The in-built [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) function provides a `frac` argument to give the fraction contained in the sample.

If your `DataFrame` of people is `people_df`:

```
percent_sampled = 27
sample_df = people_df.sample(frac = percent_sampled/100)

people_df['is_selected'] = people_df.index.isin(sample_df.index)
```

Comment: This make sense, thank you.  However I'm getting an error.  "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.  Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Comment: This is a silly warning that `pandas` incessantly throws, for very little good reason. Please read the discussion here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

I would recommend simply suppressing the warning by using
`pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None`
after you import `pandas`.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = len(df) 
idx = np.arange(n)
idx = random.shuffle(idx)
*selected_idx = idx[:int(0.27*n)] 
selected_df = df[df.index.isin(selected_idx)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a dataframe with 100 random numbers in column 0:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame(range(100))
random.shuffle(a[0])
```

Using random.sample to choose 27 random numbers from the list, WITHOUT repetition: (replace 27 with 0.27*int(len(a[0]) if you want to define this as percentage)

```
choices = random.sample(list(a[0]),27)
```

Using np.where to assign boolean values to new column in dataframe:

```
a['Bool'] = np.where(a[0].isin(choices),True,False)
```